Не могу сбросить ноутбук msi до заводских настроек помощи f3
Запускаю ноут msi нажимая на f3. Меня закидывает в меня где я выбираю:
Поиск и устранение неисправностей => Restore MSI factory settings => System Parition Recovery
Это есть в инструкции от ноута и видео на ютубе, но потом мне выдает ошибку, что нужно попробовать позже, и ничего не меняется
Как написано в ошибке:

the recovery a procedure from RecoveryDVD hasn't been successfully
finished. If you wish to recovery it again please re-boot from
recovery dvd #1 later.

Ошибка появляется после System Parition Recovery

По моему опыту, все эти вендорские системы восстановления - неработающая помойка. Возьми чистую винду и накати по-нормальному.
